# Interaction between functor, applicative and Monad

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, applicative

I am totally new to Haskell and I am trying to understand better how functor, applicative and monad work together. Below in my example:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative

data FooBar a = Foo a | Bar a deriving (Show)

myf :: FooBar Int -> FooBar Int
myf (Bar a) = Foo (a * 10)
myf (Foo a) = Bar (a * 10)

instance Functor FooBar where
    fmap func (Foo val) = Bar (func val)
    fmap func (Bar val) = Foo (func val)

instance Applicative FooBar where
    pure = Foo
    (Foo f) <*> (Foo x) = Foo (f x)
    (Foo f) <*> (Bar x) = Foo (f x)
    (Bar f) <*> (Foo x) = Bar (f x)
    (Bar f) <*> (Bar x) = Bar (f x)

instance Monad FooBar where
    return = Foo
    (Foo x) >>= f = f x
    (Bar x) >>= f = f x

main = putStrLn $ show $ Foo (+3) <*> Foo 5 >>= myf
```

What I am trying to achieve is "piping" the value from a Functor/Applicative via monad's bind but I get an error in the `main` line:

```
ghc: No instance for (Num (FooBar Int)) arising from a use of `+'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (FooBar Int))
In the first argument of `Foo', namely `(+ 3)'
In the first argument of `(<*>)', namely `Foo (+ 3)'
In the first argument of `(>>=)', namely `Foo (+ 3) <*> Foo 5'
```

Something similar happens if I replace the Applicative with the Functor like this:

```
main = putStrLn $ show $ (+3) <$> Foo 5 >>= myf
```

Is actually possible what I am trying to do or there is a mistake in my definitions?

**EDIT**
This is a cleaner solution:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative

data FooBar a = Foo a | Bar a deriving (Show)

myf :: Int -> FooBar Int
myf (a) = return (a * 10)

instance Functor FooBar where
    fmap func (Foo val) = Foo (func val)
    fmap func (Bar val) = Bar (func val)

instance Applicative FooBar where
    pure = Foo
    (Foo f) <*> something = fmap f something
    (Bar f) <*> something = fmap f something

instance Monad FooBar where
    return = Foo
    (Foo x) >>= f = f x
    (Bar x) >>= f = f x

main = putStrLn $ show $ (+) <$> Bar(19) <*> (Foo 3) >>= myf
```

Comment: There is a problem with myf, the binding operator (>>=) has type ma -> (a -> mb) -> mb. It injects a value of type 'a' into the monadic context and myf doesn't do that.

Comment: @felipez what you say is correct, indeed if I replace the function with myf :: Int -> FooBar Int myf (a) = Foo (a * 10) it will work but it won't be able to switch between Foo and Bar types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are trying to understand the relationship between `Functor`,  `Applicative`, and `Monad`, you might like to know that your `Monad` and `Applicative` instances are incompatible.   `(<*>)` must behave the same way as [`Control.Monad.ap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:ap):

```
ap :: (Monad m) => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
ap mf mx = mf >>= (\f -> mx >>= (\x -> return (f x)))
```

but you have:

```
Bar id <*>  Bar 0 = Bar 0
Bar id `ap` Bar 0 = Foo 0
```

In fact, what is causing this is also causing a monad law to be violated:

```
m >>= return = m
```

but you have

```
Bar 0 >>= return = Foo 0
```

There is also an applicative law violated caused by the same thing.

You cannot simply throw away the information of whether the value was constructed with `Foo` or `Bar` the way you are. *Since `return = Foo`*, you need to make sure that `Foo` behaves "purely" -- i.e. combining with it (in `(<*>)` or `(>>=)`) does not change the structure of the other argument.  One possible way out of this is to always have `Bar` "taint" the computation:

```
-- Since we have a Foo, we need to preserve whatever f does:
Foo x >>= f = f x
Bar x >>= f = case f x of   
                  -- If f x returned a Foo, we need to preserve Bar from the left arg:
                  Foo y -> Bar y
                  -- We can do whatever we like with this clause:
                  Bar y -> Bar y
```

Then use `ap` to find out what your `Applicative` instance should be. Interesting to note, this is now isomorphic to [`Writer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.0.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Lazy.html#t:Writer) [`Any`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Any).

Comment: Thing go awry even sooner: the `Functor` instance fails to satisfy `fmap id ≡ id`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, oh yeah, I didn't even see that!

Comment: yes even the functor itself is wrong and thanks to highlight all the problems - it helped. I put this as the right answer :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is here:

```
myf :: FooBar Int -> FooBar Int
```

The above causes trouble when you use

```
something >>= myf
```

because it requires `something` to have type `FooBar (FooBar Int)`. 
This in turn makes numeric constants to be of type `FooBar Int` and not `Int`,
and `(+)` operate on "numbers" of type `FooBar Int`. This triggers the
type error.

Maybe you simply want to use

```
myf something
```

instead. In your particular case,

```
main = putStrLn $ show $ myf $ Foo (+3) <$> Foo 5
```

Comment: please check my answer above to felipez

Comment: @Randomize I'm not suggesting to change the type, but how you apply the function. I edited to make it clearer.

Comment: what you said it was clear to me. What I am trying to achieve is actually writing down a "myf" that works with monad's bind to get the same result as in your case.

Comment: @Randomize I see. I think that's impossible though, since to use `>>= myf` the function should have type `Int -> FooInt b`, but then it loses access to the constructors `Foo` and `Bar` you want to swap in the input.